# PHP Sorting from Serialized data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with clients in it, the usual data, names, addresses, phone numbers etc etc i also have a field which is called 'roles' in which a client ticks off what they like to do i.e coding, graphic design, illustrations etc etc .. this data gets pushed into the field serialized with each roles code, the following is an example.

```
a:3:{s:4:"_wfa";s:2:"on";s:3:"_CS";s:2:"on";s:3:"_CM";s:2:"on";}
```

On a 'viewall' page, i need to output all the details for a user that has ticked a specific box, as an example, i need to output all users that have ticked the '_wfa' box.

I hope this makes sense, i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Cheers,

Comment: you have a single field holding a json object? You're going to have to parse the fields individually. Are you trying to do this in SQL?

Comment: That's not a JSON object. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never have more than one value in a single column of a row. Store the roles in their own database table, with the user's ID, and you will be able to simply ask MySQL for the users with a role as desired.

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (user_id INT, role_name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO user_roles (1, '_wfa');
INSERT INTO user_roles (1, '_CS');
INSERT INTO user_roles (1, '_CM');

SELECT users.id FROM users INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.id = user_roles.user_id WHERE user_roles.role_name = '_wfa';
```

Comment: Interesting ... How do i do an insert statement if the roles are dynamic?

Comment: INSERT INTO user_roles ($user_id, '$role_name')? The role names are arbitrary strings here already.

Answer (score 2):

You should normalise that into a table. Having it serialised means you can not use any of the benefits of SQL on it, and also that parsing it requires PHP (or custom code for other language).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, how could i put normalised data into the database if the 'roles' are dynamic?

Comment: @Chris: You really should learn more about relational database theory to "normalize" data properly

Answer (score 2):

MySQL, or any database, can not unserialize data performed by an external programming language.  The only way to get the data out, is to pull it out and unserialize in PHP before you can use the data.

The only way to get any value out of using a database is to store data in it, using tables and native data types to enforce data consistency.  Normalization and referential integrity work to minimize data duplication while enforcing business rules.

Transitioning to SQL, objects become tables -- they're like arrays.  Object attributes become columns, but when an object contains an array of other objects - that attribute gets promoted to being a table...  Normalization means taking things like roles, and making a code table for them that you can refer to in other tables.