# read element of serialize field in mysql

Tags: mysql, serialization

i ran this query on mysql:

```
select rc_details from apitbl limit 1;
```

the result is

```
a:7:{s:6:"itemid";s:9:"PCO FLEXI";s:2:"op";s:1:"P";s:3:"cir";s:1:"*";s:3:"api";s:1:"3";s:3:"loc";s:1:"P";s:4:"type";s:1:"F";s:4:"mode";s:1:"T";}
```

My Problem:

i want to extract elements from the serialize fields to run query as:

```
select rc_details from apitbl where (itemid='PCO FLEXI');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sorting from Serialized data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141416/php-sorting-from-serialized-data)

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array/4116482#4116482

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do it:

```
SELECT rc_details FROM apitbl WHERE rc_details REGEXP '.*"itemid";s:[0-9]+:"PCO FLEXI".*'
```

Anyway it's much better to create additional table and store this info there.